# Python output to valid JSON from a FOR loop

Tags: python, json, loops, boto3

OK Guys, i'm brand new to Python.

I have started using it at work to query AWS with Boto3

My first task is to build a script to query users in AWS with MFA, the initial script works and returns all users which don't have a MFA Device, pretty simple really.

What i'm wanting to do is export the list to a JSON file so I can then consume the data within an Angular application to display the report.

When I run the code I get a JSON output but it's incorrect, its missing the comma and closing the JSON after each object instead of creating a complete singular JSON output.

My code is as follows:

```
import json
# boto code here

for user in iam.list_users()['Users']:
    mfa = iam.list_mfa_devices(UserName=user['UserName'])
    if len(mfa['MFADevices']) == 0:
        q = []

        q.append({"account": item['alias'], "Username": 
user['UserName'], "MFA": "No MFA Enabled"})
        print json.dumps(q, indent=4)
```

Result format is:

```
[
  {
    "Username": "Username", 
    "MFA": "No MFA Enabled", 
    "account": "account"
  }
]
[
  {
    "Username": "Username", 
    "MFA": "No MFA Enabled", 
    "account": "account"
  }
]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many valid JSON-formats. One of them is a list with dictionaries:

> [ {}, {} ]

I suggest you try this:

```
import json
# boto code here
q = []
for user in iam.list_users()['Users']:
    mfa = iam.list_mfa_devices(UserName=user['UserName'])
    if len(mfa['MFADevices']) == 0:
        q.append({"account": item['alias'], "Username": 
user['UserName'], "MFA": "No MFA Enabled"})

print json.dumps(q, indent=4)
```

Comment: Nearly worked, but seems to be duplicating and multiplying the results creating a huge list

Comment: @MatthewWhite Hmm can you share some of the data in iam.list_users()['Users']

Comment: I'm afraid I can't but I think it is actually working, basically my script assumes roles in AWS and goes through several accounts, it then returns the results for each account, so it's closing the json objects for each account, so I believe your fix works, thank you

Comment: @MatthewWhite Glad I could help. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Nearly worked, but seems to be duplicating and multiplying the results creating a huge list

```
[
 {
    "Username": "Username", 
    "MFA": "No MFA Enabled", 
    "account": "Account"
 }
]
[
 {
    "Username": "Username", 
    "MFA": "No MFA Enabled", 
    "account": "Account"
 }, 
 {
    "Username": "Username", 
    "MFA": "No MFA Enabled", 
    "account": "Account"
 }
]
[
  {
    "Username": "Username", 
    "MFA": "No MFA Enabled", 
    "account": "Account"
  }, 
  {
    "Username": "Username", 
    "MFA": "No MFA Enabled", 
    "account": "Account"
  }, 
  {
    "Username": "Username", 
    "MFA": "No MFA Enabled", 
    "account": "Account"
  }
]
[
  {
    "Username": "Username", 
    "MFA": "No MFA Enabled", 
    "account": "Account"
  }, 
  {
    "Username": "Username", 
    "MFA": "No MFA Enabled", 
    "account": "Account"
  }, 
  {
    "Username": "Username", 
    "MFA": "No MFA Enabled", 
    "account": "Account"
  }, 
  {
    "Username": "Username", 
    "MFA": "No MFA Enabled", 
    "account": "Account"
  }
]
```